# Component diffing

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

This question will probably be an easy one.

Supposing the following Svelte component:

```html
{#if condition}
  <A>
{:else}
  <B>
{/if}
```

where A and B are other Svelte components. The question is:

- is B *surgically* diffed against A?
- is A replaced entirely by B?

There are two use cases from which this question arises:

- a poor man routing can be implemented with branching as previously shown. It is interesting to minimize updates between routed components when they are similar enough
- I have a case where B is A with a twist and I am not sure whether to just let the compiler do its work or use the parent component with extra parameters to encode the variation between A and B:

```html
...
...
{#if condition}
  ... The A-only part
{/if}
...
{#if other condition}
 ... The B-only part
{/if}
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A is replaced entirely with B, as with virtual DOM algorithms. This is only partly for simplicity, it's also for correctness — A and B are *conceptually* different, even if they have a similar structure, so it's important that the new component doesn't inherit any state that was in the old DOM (ongoing CSS animations, focus states, etc). 'Surgical' applies to state changes *within* a component.

Comment: true I forgot that a Svelte component is more than the markup. That said, vDOM (at least in React) would not redraw the whole thing I think, except if B would start with a different tag than A (at least it was like that a year ago or so). Alright, so I will merge A and B in a X with conditional branching.

Comment: React behaves the same way — if it sees a different component constructor, it will completely discard the old instance and all of its elements